# Regex character preceding search

Tags: regex, datetime

I have a the following regex expression which finds dates in a text file:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})
```

I want to find the character that precedes this search string. Can anyone point me in the right direction. The preceding character is a , (comma) which I want to search and replace.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It's always a comma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to accomplish this:

```
/,(?=(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))/
```

This pattern will match the comma, but only if it's followed by something that matches the pattern you've provided in the question.  (Note that with search/replace, it will not replace the date)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `,` to your regex. Then it will only match instances of dates preceeded by commas:

```
/,((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))/
```

The original regex is wrapped in `()` and will be available as the first sub-match.